# Python class instance vs. class variables

Tags: python

I am trying to define a list as an instance variable within a class but it is acting as a class variable.

```
class THING:
    def __init__(self, name, stuff):
        self.name = name
        self.dict = []
        for item in stuff:
            self.dict.append(item)

    def getname(self):
        return self.name

    def getlist(self):
        return self.dict

    def inc_datecnt(self,date):
        for item in self.dict:
            if item.has_key(date): 
                item[date] += 1



list = []
dates=['July1,2015', 'July2,2015', 'July3,2015']
datecnts = []
for date in dates:
    datecnts.append({date : 0})

list.append(THING('A', datecnts))
list.append(THING('B', datecnts))


for item in list:
    print "\n", item.getname()
    item.inc_datecnt('July1,2015')
    for subitem in item.getlist():
        print subitem
```

---

When I execute this I get:

```
A
{'July1,2015': 1}
{'July2,2015': 0}
{'July3,2015': 0}

B
{'July1,2015': 2}
{'July2,2015': 0}
{'July3,2015': 0}
```

---

I seem to be increment a single class dictionary element for July1,2015 when I want (and expect) to be incrementing an instance variable.

Help

Comment: You reused `datecnts` to construct the two instances of `THING`, and while you created a new list the `dict` inside are the same between the two.

Comment: Maybe you could print type(item) to make sure that the object is THING and not dict

Comment: Python doesn't exactly have a way of printing this out so you'll have to make a `def __str__(self)` if you want to just print out the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing `datecnts` list to your `THING` object's constructor, you are just passing the reference (and list is mutable and dict are mutable) , hence if you make any changes to the dict for `A` THING object, it would reflect in `B` , since `B` also has the same reference. You should try to do `copy.deepcopy` of `datecnts` and send that to `A` and `B` separately.

Example -

```
import copy
list.append(THING('A', copy.deepcopy(datecnts)))
list.append(THING('B', copy.deepcopy(datecnts)))
```

Comment: Accepting the answer is by clicking tick mark on the left side.